# Custom permissions in Django DRF class based view

Tags: python, django, rest, permissions

I'm trying to set custom permissions in a `ModelViewSet`. I want to allow any authenticated user to list and retrieve items but only Admin and Manager can create, update, and destroy.

Here is the relevant code in views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import MenuItemSerializer 
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .permissions import IsManager
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser

class Showitem(CustomThrottleMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MenuItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MenuItemSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = []
    filterset_fields = ['category', 'title','price','featured']
    ordering_fields = ['title','title', 'category']
    search_fields=['title','category__title']

    def get_permissions(self):
        #Override default method. Set custom permissions for each action
        if self.action in ['update', 'partial_update', 'destroy', 'create']:
            self.permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsManager]
        elif self.action in ['list', 'retrieve']:
            self.permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        #return default method if none of the above is true
        return super().get_permissions()
```

Here permissions.py

```
class IsManager(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
              return request.user.groups.filter(name='manager').exists()  
            return False
```

When I try to post a new Item as admin user via the API endpoint everything works.
If I try the same as Manager I get:

> "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are performing the permission check for admin and for the manager at the same time:

```py
self.permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsManager]
...
return super().get_permissions()
```

Django will check if you are both an admin and a manager.
I think this should solve your issue. [Django Rest Framework get_permissions require one permission or other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610037/django-rest-framework-get-permissions-require-one-permission-or-other)